# Istio Envoy Sidecar - run it as Gateway along side with application

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, servicemesh

Is it possible to configure Istio sidecar(envoy) that runs along side with application to terminate tls as Istio Ingress Gateway?

The goal is to terminate my application TLS on outbound/inbound and encrypt with Istio mTLS when connecting to other sidecar and encrypt it back with my certificates before forwarding the traffic to upstream.

If so, please refer to some documentation.

Comment: Hi Arsen, you can setup such a solution using a combination of Istio Gateway with Passthrough mode [1] and Destination Rule with ClientTLSSettings: https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ClientTLSSettings

Though I think we can get to a better solution if you share a little more information what you want to achieve

[1] https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ClientTLSSettings

Comment: @Rinor my apps are all on mTLS. 
My goal is to be able to access layer 7 data e.g headers to be able to redirect traffic. right now sidecar is doing Passthrough cause traffic is encrypted

Comment: I suppose you have multiple containers within the sidecar to which you want to route the request? To me a viable approach sounds to do the termination at the Gateway and then use a Sidecar Custom Resource to configure the sidecar ingress https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/sidecar/#IstioIngressListener

I didn't have to do this, but in theory it should work. But is that your intention?

Comment: @Rinor my applications expect mTLS connection. What I am trying to do is make envoy terminate that mTLS on outbound and send plain http to another Service's sidecar which will encrypt the traffic before sending in to my app.

Comment: Can you update your question with a diagram?